# Sending Ajax Data as Array Different than Sending as Manual String

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to send an array as json for an ajax request, but for some reason, if I build up an array of data I want to send and pass that into the data attribute, it is different than if I manually just type in what I want. Here is an example:

**Works:**

```
$.ajax({
  method: "PUT",
  url: restURL,
  data: {
     id: 1,
     number: 99
  }
});
```

What the form data in chrome dev console looks like for network request:

```
id:1
number:99
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
var array = [];
array.push({
    id: 1,
    number: 99
});

$.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    url: restURL,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(array)
})
```

What the form data in chrome dev console looks like for network request:

```
[{"id":1,"number":99}]:
```

---

I need the data to match what the first one outputs in the dev console because that is what our server expects, but I cannot figure out how to get this to work with building an array beforehand. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the first example you do not send any array. It is just one object. What is expected format on the server for array of data?

Comment: @OrestHera the format in the first example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first example you are sending form encode key/value pairs.

In the second all you are sending is a string ...that happens to be json ... but all it is is a value with no key.

Try:

```
data: {myArray: array}
```

then receive at server using the key `myArray`

Answer (score 1):

As @charlietfl said Your problem is that you are setting **data** to an **array** where the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
says that the data argument must be an **Object**

a solution may be to make your array as an attribute of the data object, 
example :

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({
    id: 1,
    number: 99
});

var myObj = { data: arr};

$.ajax({
  method: "PUT",
  url: restURL,
  data: myObj
});
```

Hope this helps